# How to populate /etc/network/interfaces automatically

Tags: networking, udev, interface

I am trying to populate `/etc/network/interfaces` with a dhcp config for all interfaces at the first system boot (Debian 7.6 server).

I modified the script in : `/lib/udev/write_net_rules`
by adding:

```
cat > /etc/network/interface.new <<EOT
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto $INTERFACE
allow-hotplug $INTERFACE
iface $INTERFACE inet dhcp

EOT
```

I removed the content of `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, and rebooted my device.

`70-persistent-net.rules` was correctly populated but not `/etc/network/interfaces.new`

I have tried simple **echo** in many other files and it also does not work.

Do you have a method to configure dhcp for all interfaces ?

Comment: You _do_ know you're creating `/etc/network/interface.new` and not `/etc/network/interfaces`, right?

Comment: yes, but `/etc/network/interface.new` does not exist too

Comment: Where exactly did you add this code?

Comment: on different place, I even tested at the beginning of the script. nothing is written regardless of the destination, unless I push in `70-persistent-net.rules`